# Why Does Time Machine Fail to Delete Old Backups?

Tags: backup, time-machine

This on a 2017 iMac running Catalina with a 500GB boot drive which has 180GB free.

The Time Machine backup is a 1TB partition on a WD MyBook 25EE 3TB drive.

This worked fine for a few years. Some time in the middle of last year TM stopped removing old backups, eventually filled up the partition and refused to do any more backups. I tried to use tmutil to delete old backups, but that didn't work. I ended up erasing the partition and starting over. That was on November 11th of last year.

Now I find that none of the old backups (beginning November 11th) have been removed:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ ls -la /Volumes/TM/Backups.backupdb/MrMuscle
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@ 257 root  admin  8738 Jan 21 05:52 .
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root  admin   204 Nov 10 10:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  admin   136 Jan 20 15:13 2020-11-10-105328
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  admin   136 Nov 11 18:43 2020-11-10-162243
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  admin   136 Nov 11 21:16 2020-11-10-201658
<many lines snipped>
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  admin   136 Jan 20 15:40 2021-01-20-081356
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root  admin   136 Jan 20 15:44 2021-01-20-121042
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root  admin   442 Jan 20 14:09 2021-01-20-140908
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root  admin   442 Jan 20 17:14 2021-01-20-171406
drwxr-xr-x@  13 root  admin   442 Jan 21 05:47 2021-01-21-054733
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  admin    17 Jan 21 05:47 Latest -> 2021-01-21-054733
```

Note that ls shows a total of 8 items. That's obviously incorrect:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ ls -la /Volumes/TM/Backups.backupdb/MrMuscle | wc -l
     259
```

TM preferences says that the oldest backup is Yesterday at 14:09. And, if I "Enter Time Machine" that's the oldest backup that is accessible.

If I list the local snapshots, it only lists items from yesterday and today:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
Snapshots for volume group containing disk /:
com.apple.TimeMachine.2021-01-20-060557.local
com.apple.TimeMachine.2021-01-20-070741.local
<many lines snipped>
com.apple.TimeMachine.2021-01-21-053743.local
com.apple.TimeMachine.2021-01-21-060436.local
com.bombich.ccc.039656C5-DEBE-4D49-8C0B-225D6B822607.2021-01-11-010839
com.bombich.ccc.1593C4E4-80E2-4E86-BFAD-09F6BC19C644.2021-01-18-010823
com.bombich.ccc.DE0A2A8B-C128-4A8B-816A-42EFC64E5BB5.2021-01-16-011013
```

So, what's going on here? Why is Time Machine not deleting old backups to free up space for new backups? How can if fix this?

Comment: What are the Carbon Copy Cloner snapshots? How did they get there? do you CCC to the same drive as Time Machine?

Comment: The CCC snapshots were put there by CCC. I don't know why it puts them there as I actually back up with CCC to a different volume. [Leveraging Snapshots on APFS Volumes](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/leveraging-snapshots-on-apfs-volumes)